# How to get the date one month before from current date, when current date is January?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, rangeslider

I used a plugin called jQRnageSlider and tried to get the date and time label showed in the slider, but when I scroll back the slider to last year, the month `12` turns out to be `11` eventually.

[image]

Normal case if I don't scroll back to last year.

[image]

It jumped to Nov 2016 immediately

That should be the issue of date formatting issue. Can anyone help?

```
$(".date-range-slider").dateRangeSlider({    
  ...

  formatter: function(val){
    var days = ('0' + val.getDate()).slice(-2),
    month = ('0' + val.getMonth() + 1).slice(-2),
    year = val.getFullYear(),
    hour = ('0' + val.getHours()).slice(-2),
    min = ('0' + val.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    return days + "-" + month + "-" + year + " " + hour + ":" + min;
  }
});
```

Comment: If you are using date/time functions a lot across your app, I recommend looking at moment.js - it'll solve a lot of these issues for you.

Comment: The problem may be here `('0' + val.getMonth() + 1)`, because first comes string concatenation `('0' + month)` which results in string and then you append another `1` to that string. You probably want `('0' + (val.getMonth() + 1))`.

Comment: Your function works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/86hdnnno/

Maybe the "val" argument doesn't have the month 11 as December?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that line:

`month = ('0' + val.getMonth() + 1).slice(-2)`

You want to sum it mathematically not as string, so you should do:

`month = ('0' + (val.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)`

Check the snippet to see what your code is actually returning:

```js
var val = new Date();
document.write('0' + val.getMonth() + 1)
```

And what returns corrected version:

```js
var val = new Date();
document.write('0' + (val.getMonth() + 1))
```

Comment: yeah, I found that myself too. A silly mistake. Thanks anyway